# Why did deleting .git delete all tracked files?

Tags: git

I wanted to recreate a git repository.  My understanding is that by deleting the ".git" folder, I could start from a fresh history.  However, removing the folder seemed to delete all *tracked* files, leaving only untracked files on disk.

I was able to restore the files from backup, but I don't understand what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

All tracked files are stored in `.git/index` file, if you remove that file, all files become untracked. When you remove all files from `.git/` folder, you're basically erasing/destroying your whole repository.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, so:

- To [rebuild the index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38274887/55075), run: `git reset && git add -u`.
- To re-create Git after removal of `.git`, run: `git init`.
- To re-add all untracked files, run: `git add -A` and commit them.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably in a bare repository, where no working files are available, you have only the repository. So if you delete the git directory, you remove everything. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28428742 and other answers in this question.

Also, whatever you want to achieve you should never play with the `.git` repository. Use the `git` command to achieve your goals, and consider `.git` directories to be off-limits, and only for the tool internal working.